# Why do we need to write a native sql query in a hbm.xml rather than in a string of java file?

Tags: java, sql, xml, hibernate

Lets say for example I have the following query (simple one but I know we use native sql queries only when we have complex ones which cannot be written as named queries)

```
String query = "select top 1 id from comp_job_processing_cycle order by start_date desc"
```

Now I was told that we are supposed to write these native sql queries in somefile.hbm.xml file rather than the way I have written in a java file. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

My reasons are

- Global access to that query. If you write inline query, you may need to copy paste.
- Your code looks beautiful. Those big big queries in source code looks ugly.
- Maintenance will be easy. If you scatter your queries everywhere in code, later it's hard to maintain them.

And I usually place respective queries in respective bean mapping file.

Comment: On the other hand, that's yet another file to hunt down when debugging, and one more obstacle to finding out what the code is up to. If you want to print your code on a T-shirt, "looks beautiful" counts. If you want maintainable code, other things trump that. There are only rare code manipulations which need to consider all queries at once.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Fair points. My definition to `beautiful` here is that, `reader friendly`. :) The last point in your comment may pushing OP to do so.